# Python/JS regex to match any number that is less than X

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I have some JSON data in a text file, something like:

```
..."priority":1,...
..."priority":3,...
..."priority":5,...
```

what I want to do is match all lines where priority is less than or equal to 3.

so the matches would be:

```
..."priority":1,...
..."priority":3,...
```

So my basic regex might look like:

```
/"priority":[0-9],/
```

and a simple script to test this

```
const regex = /"priority":[0-9],/;

const str = '{"dateCreated":"2016-12-31T06:41:32.298Z","pid":15154,"count":1,"uid":"77d55631-36ab-4805-aa17-1c984c8d4d04","priority":1,"isRead":false,"line":"foo bar baz"}';

console.log(regex.test(str));   // true
```

so this will match any number 0-9, but how can I match X and below? Where X might be a 2 digit number?

Is this a concise way to do that somehow?

The raw data in the file looks like this:

```
{"dateCreated":"2016-12-31T20:31:42.928Z","pid":5502,"count":0,"uid":"b21ac5eb-e25f-411c-80e9-955ff6eab964","priority":2,"isRead":false,"line":"foo bar baz"}
{"dateCreated":"2016-12-31T20:31:43.058Z","pid":5502,"count":1,"uid":"19f69863-7bf7-45f1-99b8-30fe332e88b9","priority":1,"isRead":false,"line":"foo bar baz"}
{"dateCreated":"2016-12-31T20:31:43.262Z","pid":5502,"count":2,"uid":"ee8ca050-d1b5-4787-8d9f-78b17a9c4e9e","priority":1,"isRead":false,"line":"foo bar baz"}
{"dateCreated":"2016-12-31T20:31:43.462Z","pid":5502,"count":3,"uid":"40fdbf37-0caf-4dde-b6fa-8522cd333b6e","priority":1,"isRead":false,"line":"foo bar baz"}
{"dateCreated":"2016-12-31T20:31:43.666Z","pid":5502,"count":4,"uid":"d1928b11-e93c-413a-8e4e-49ac8a7b38b5","priority":1,"isRead":false,"line":"foo bar baz"}
{"dateCreated":"2016-12-31T20:31:43.865Z","pid":5502,"count":5,"uid":"9fdff4bc-5126-43f9-85c6-d1212bac777b","priority":1,"isRead":false,"line":"foo bar baz"}
{"dateCreated":"2016-12-31T20:31:44.071Z","pid":5502,"count":6,"uid":"3058cc78-eea6-4de9-96de-69c107b73724","priority":1,"isRead":false,"line":"foo bar baz"}
{"dateCreated":"2016-12-31T20:31:44.271Z","pid":5502,"count":7,"uid":"52899ff3-2c17-4392-9409-a24152d4d15c","priority":1,"isRead":false,"line":"foo bar baz"}
{"dateCreated":"2016-12-31T20:31:44.468Z","pid":5502,"count":8,"uid":"a775cd96-be9e-4713-83d3-92441d73443d","priority":1,"isRead":false,"line":"foo bar baz"}
{"dateCreated":"2016-12-31T20:31:44.675Z","pid":5502,"count":9,"uid":"4fedb82b-1fb9-4049-870e-ff3bdf32fd5e","priority":2,"isRead":false,"line":"foo bar baz"}
{"dateCreated":"2016-12-31T20:31:44.877Z","pid":5502,"count":10,"uid":"c3fd144c-0182-4777-80a8-ce5db0da6525","priority":2,"isRead":false,"line":"foo bar baz"}
{"dateCreated":"2016-12-31T20:31:45.075Z","pid":5502,"count":11,"uid":"70fde6ea-f57c-4d2c-9eb0-d2b04fae23f2","priority":1,"isRead":false,"line":"foo bar baz"}
{"dateCreated":"2016-12-31T20:31:45.277Z","pid":5502,"count":12,"uid":"540db3c7-bfe0-4d09-b4b6-d8922455c8d5","priority":3,"isRead":false,"line":"foo bar baz"}
{"dateCreated":"2016-12-31T20:31:45.483Z","pid":5502,"count":13,"uid":"1eca7c3b-be01-4457-885f-b7cb807952aa","priority":1,"isRead":false,"line":"foo bar baz"}
{"dateCreated":"2016-12-31T20:31:45.683Z","pid":5502,"count":14,"uid":"d7f3cf02-e302-49d5-9977-fac592349335","priority":1,"isRead":false,"line":"foo bar baz"}
{"dateCreated":"2016-12-31T20:31:45.881Z","pid":5502,"count":15,"uid":"8760aa12-5c10-456f-8ae1-b570bc939ff7","priority":2,"isRead":false,"line":"foo bar baz"}
{"dateCreated":"2016-12-31T20:31:46.087Z","pid":5502,"count":16,"uid":"152a51da-d253-4245-999d-6518318c305d","priority":1,"isRead":false,"line":"foo bar baz"}
```

(It's newline separate JSON data)

Comment: Tried this? `[0-3][0-9]?`

Comment: with your implementation, could you simply have /"priority":(\d+)/ and then just throw out all matches where int(match_object.group(1)) >= X  ?

Comment: Regular expressions are a bad tool for this job. If `X` is a number with digits `Y` and `Z`, then the expression you are looking for is something like this `r"\d|[0-%d]\d|%d[0-%d]" % (Y-1,Y,Z)`.

Comment: Regex is for matching string patterns it doesn't really understand numbers so much as the character that represents that number and then only between 0-9.

Comment: Any reaon you do not want to `json.loads` the text and then use `filter` on the resultant data structure?

Comment: actually, for some reason that didn't occur to me until a moment ago, Python is so foreign to me, but yeah that would work! But for the sake of the question, it would be nice to figure it out.

Comment: @DYZ that's a really clever answer, the but it would need to be tweaked so that the initial "\d" didn't match unless it stood alone, otherwise, it would match the 1 in 14, say, without realizing that that is greater than 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a good case for `regex`. Instead, you should be loading the file using the json module, and then simply testing for the value of "priority".

```
import json

with open('./sample_json.json', 'r') as json_data_file:
    json_data = json_data_file.readlines()
json_data_file.closed
```

Using a list comprehension, we create a list of  `dicts`, one for each line in `json_data`:

```
json_array = [json.loads(line) for line in json_data]
```

Finally, we run your greater-than less-than test for each `dict` in `json_array` and print each result:   for line in json_array:

```
    if line['priority'] < 20:
        print("Success!")
```

---

> Note that we could accomplish this by using a `for` loop instead of the list comprehension, with the same result:

```
json_array = []
for line in json_data:
    json_array.append(json.loads(line))
```

---

To learn more about the `json` module, read up on it here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

---

For easier copy/pasting, here's the uninterrupted code:

---

```
import json

with open('./sample_json.json', 'r') as json_data_file:
    json_data = json_data_file.readlines()
json_data_file.closed

# Using list comprehension to populate json_array
json_array = [json.loads(line) for line in json_data]

# Using for loop to populate json_array
json_array = []
for line in json_data:
    json_array.append(json.loads(line))

for line in json_array:
    if line['priority'] < 20:
        print("Success!")
```

---

Note that with the parsed JSON as a `dict`, you have access to any of the keys for each line of your JSON:

```
for item in json_array:
    for key in item.keys():
        print("KEY:", key, "VALUE:", json_array[0][key])
    print()
```

Comment: Well, in this case, each line is a JSON, but the whole file cannot be read and parsed as a whole. Only lines can be parsed individually. Think of this as log files with JSON data as the raw data. But yes, it's better to parse each line as JSON, and then look at the data, than use regex, agreed

Comment: Can you add a section of your file that shows the structure, before and after the JSON?

Comment: Excellent. Thanks.

Comment: For all I know, using regex might actually be more performant than JSON parse, although I don't know about that. Also, I might be eventually writing this in C, and in that case, it might be easier to use regex than JSON parsing in C, dunno?

Comment: It would be pretty easy to test both methods, but that would a good candidate for a different Question. As far as C implementations, there are several JSON libraries in that world, too. http://www.digip.org/jansson/, https://bitbucket.org/yarosla/nxjson and https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON, for example.

Comment: well, the only next reasonable question is - if you had to guess which do you think will be faster? regex or json parse in C? :)

Comment: Within python, I'd guess the JSON over regex. Within C, likely JSON over regex. There are a lot of things that might make the difference. Out of the scope here, anyway. Good luck with this stuff!

Comment: @AlexanderMills Though that would definitely be a good candidate for an SO Qustion of its own.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, here is the project in  question https://github.com/ORESoftware/observable-persistent-queue

Comment: Basically need a persistent queue, but don't want to have to install Redis (or can't install Redis)

Comment: I'd say try the python approach first, and check for adequate performance.

Comment: @AlexanderMills You're welcome. I'll check out your project.

Comment: thanks it's definitely not ready for publication yet but figured I'd share with you now otherwise you wouldn't have any context for it  :) I'm in the process of implementing priority queue features to the queue and I should probably get the tests working well before anything. I also wrote "live-mutex" to support OPQ, because I wasn't see any highly robust locking libraries that don't need Redis.

Answer (score 1):

Using JSON load/parse etc, is definitely right way to do this, but in terms of solving this with regex

The brute force method, like so:

```
"\"priority\":(1|2|3|4),"
```

should work just fine for smaller integers, and is probably pretty non-error-prone.